# Context-free grammar from language

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I'm trying to come up with a context-free grammar for the following language:

$$L = \{a^mb^nc^{m+n}\mid 0 \le n \le m\}$$

My thinking is that i can rewrite this to

$$L = \{a^mb^nc^nc^m\mid 0 \le n \le m\}$$

and then create the grammar

$$
\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow aSc \mid B\\
B &\rightarrow bBc \mid \epsilon
\end{align*}
$$

The problem is that this grammar doesn't capture $0 \le n \le m$ and I can't figure out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your language is context-free?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: is the language $L' = \{a^n b^n c^{2n} \mid n \ge 0\}$ context-free?